# Using Jison to convert a list of commands into an array of objects

Tags: parsing, bison, flex-lexer, yacc, jison

I am trying to use [Jison](http://zaa.ch/jison/), which is a JS port of Bison, the parser generator. My goal is to convert this input:

```
foo(10)
bar()
foo(28)
baz(28)
```

into this:

```
[
  { func: 'foo', arg: 10 },
  { func: 'bar' },
  { func: 'foo', arg: 28 },
  { func: 'baz', arg: 28 }
]
```

Here is my bison file:

```
%lex

%%
[0-9]+\b                  return 'INTEGER'
\(                        return 'OPEN_PAREN'
\)                        return 'CLOSE_PAREN'
[\w]+\s*(?=\()            return 'FUNC_NAME'
\n+                       return 'LINE_END'

/lex

%%
expressions
  : expressions expression
  | expression
  ;

expression
  : LINE_END
  | e LINE_END
    {return $1}
  ;

e
  : FUNC_NAME OPEN_PAREN INTEGER CLOSE_PAREN
    {$$ = { func: $1, arg: $3 };}

  | FUNC_NAME OPEN_PAREN CLOSE_PAREN
    {$$ = { func: $1 };}
  ;
```

The output of the resulting generated parser is `{ func: 'foo', arg: 10 }`. In other words, it only returns the parsed object from the first statement and ignores the rest.

I know my problem has to do with semantic value and the "right side" of `expression`, but I am pretty lost otherwise.

Any help would be extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm appending a grammar that does what you asked for. The salient changes are:

1. `LINE_END` has the regex `\n+|$` to also match the end of output.
2. I've added a `start` production whose role is only to return the final result.
3. Rewrote the `expression` production to produce arrays. I've also removed the `{return $1}` from the `e LINE_END` rule since that caused the parser to return prematurely.
4. Modified the `expressions` production to concatenate the arrays.

For the `expression` and `expressions` productions, I've used the shorthand syntax for the rules there. For instance `expression -> [$1]` is equivalent to `expression { $$ = [$1] }`.

Here is the grammar:

```
%lex

%%
[0-9]+\b                  return 'INTEGER'
\(                        return 'OPEN_PAREN'
\)                        return 'CLOSE_PAREN'
[\w]+\s*(?=\()            return 'FUNC_NAME'
\n+|$                     return 'LINE_END'

/lex

%%
start:
  expressions
  { return $1 }
  ;

expressions
  : expressions expression -> $1.concat($2)
  | expression
  ;

expression
  : LINE_END -> []
  | e LINE_END -> [$1]
  ;

e 
  : FUNC_NAME OPEN_PAREN INTEGER CLOSE_PAREN
    {$$ = { func: $1, arg: $3 };}

  | FUNC_NAME OPEN_PAREN CLOSE_PAREN
    {$$ = { func: $1 };}
  ;
```

An aside: Jison is not a port of Bison. It is a a parser generator whose functioning is *strongly inspired by Bison* but it has features that Bison does not have and there are some features of Bison that Jison does not support.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am getting an error when `\n+|$` is `LINE_END`, but when I leave it as `\n`, I get a list of objects as expected but with `'\n'`s for each blank line. If I make it `\n+`, It removes the `'\n'`s in the middle of the list but not at the beginning.

Comment: I've tried the grammar both with the [online Jison](https://zaa.ch/jison/try/) and by installing the latest Jison (0.4.18) locally. I cannot reproduce the issue you describe with getting `\n` "for each blank line". Try as I may, the array produced never has anything between expressions. However, I was able to produce a file that caused an empty string to show up at the end of in the array if the parsed text ended with a newline instead of just ending. I've edited my answer to prevent that.